# Voronoi Polygon option?

Tags: qgis-plugins, voronoi-thiessen

In Vector > Geometry Tools option, Voronoi polygon option is not there. Do we need to instal any plugin for that?

Comment: It is available in the recent version of QGIS (they removed it from the menubar previously but brought it back). Which QGIS version are you using? Also, you should still be able to select it from the **Processing Toolbox** as the tool resides in the **Processing** plugin.

Comment: I am Using QGIS 2.18.3 Version.Got it. It is available in Processing Toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

A QGIS with version `>=3.0` will have in `Geometry Tools(under vector tab)`  while an old version (2.XX) will have  in `Processing Toolbox`.